# Using an email address as a value attribute breaks my script

Tags: jquery, email, joomla

I have a Joomla website, and I'm trying to use a jQuery script I wrote that sets the "value" attribute of an input tag (with an ID of recipients) to an email address, like this:

```
jQuery('#recipients').attr('value', 'email@address.com');
```

This works outside of Joomla, but in the Joomla site, it breaks, and part of the script appears as plain text on the page.

It seems to be tripping over the @ sign. If I remove it, it works in Joomla. Is there a way to escape the @ sign, but keep the email address intact when the value attribute is set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
jQuery('#recipients').val('email@address.com');
```

Comment: Thanks! The decodeURIComponent() comment was also helpful.